# What is :exec and :export commands format in Zathura PDF viewer?

Tags: pdf-reader

It’s not documented anywhere. I’d like to bind a shortcut to export currently open page to desktop and another one to open it in gimp. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the source: [exec](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/blob/master/zathura/commands.c#L517) and [export](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/blob/master/zathura/commands.c#L417).

In the case of the "exec" command, the argument (whatever is after exec) has `$FILE` and `%` replaced by the path of the current document, and is executed.

For "export", there are two possibilities:

1. `export attachment-{name} {file_name}`
2. `export image-p{page_number}-{image_number} {file_name}`

I don't think that it's possible to automatically do what you want, as the current page is not a replaceable variable. For inspiration on what can be done, you could look at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153190/zathura-how-do-i-add-a-keybind-for-exec .